# C# inheritence child not picking up parent

Tags: c#, inheritance

In my code my child classes are not picking up my parent class for some reason.

I'm not even sure what code to give you because its so simple and should be working.

I've looked at similar code and cant see any differences. If you need more of the code just ask just as I don't want to have a huge page of code for 1 question.

well in c# the class Names text comes up in blue and its just coming up in black text wich makes me asume they arent geting picked up right. the top line is giving me the error "Expected class, delegate,enum,interface or struc"

```
WagedEmployee emp1 = new WagedEmployee

public  class Employee : Object
{
.....
}

public class WagedEmployee : Employee
{
......
}

public class SalaryEmployee : Employee 
{
.....
}
```

Comment: What is the error.  What do you expect it to do all these things would be good to know.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? From this code `emp1` should be able to be cast and used as either `Employee` and `Object` as well as `WagedEmployee`.

Comment: `if you need more of the code just ask`, no need for a -1

Comment: Anything that doesn't have a modifier won't be accessible by the child class.  Make sure all your properties, methods, etc are either public or protected.

Comment: What do your constructors look like?

Comment: WagedEmployee emp1 = new WagedEmployee should have () at the end.  WagedEmployee emp1 = new WagedEmployee();

Comment: well in c# the class Names text comes up in blue and its just coming up in black text wich makes me asume they arent geting picked up right. the top line is giving me the error "Expected class, delegate,enum,interface or struc"

Comment: @L.B, we should not need to ask the user to make the question actually answerable. The question gives no indication of what's wrong, we can't answer it, therefore the "question is unclear or not useful" downvote explanation is specifically applicable. If he follows through and improves the question, the votes may be rescinded.

Comment: @Jordan: Does the program compile? Are you getting some sort of error? Please **edit your question to include information that specifically describes the problem and your expected behavior vs. current behavior**. Please try to read your question as someone who doesn't already know what you're talking about.

Comment: @Jordan imported correct namespaces?

Comment: @Jordan, your problem is on the first line. You can't put a statement directly in a namespace, only declarations. Statements must be in methods... I suggest you start by reading a book about C#.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram, `If he follows through and improves the question, the votes may be rescinded` of course, but tomorrow I won't remember this question possibly to get back and upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you've provided, the first line doesn't appear to be inside a class of any kind.  It need to be a part of a class or struct or something.  It can't just be under the namespace.

try this:

```
public  class Employee : Object 
{ 
    ..... 
}  

public class WagedEmployee : Employee 
{ 
    ...... 
}  

public class SalaryEmployee : Employee  
{ 
    ..... 
}

public class MyTest
{
    public WagedEmployee emp1 = new WagedEmployee();
}
```

Comment: Thankyou problem solved something so simple that i over looked

Comment: Happens to me all the time!  The simplest ones are often the hardest to find!